# quantile ranking on multiple columns of a data frame and mutate the results

Tags: r, dataframe, quantile, dplyr

I have a data frame that looks as follows:

```
    AA   BB  CC   DD
aa  2.6 -0.3 2.5 2.3
bb -0.3  1.2 2.1 0.8
cc  0.5 -0.4 0.4 0.4
```

I would like to do a Quantile ranking for this data frame based on each column and mutate the ranking of each column to the Data frame. I would like to use dplyr package. I can do it for one column that results in following data frame:

```
     AA   BB  CC   DD quantile
 aa  2.6 -0.3 2.5 2.3        4
 bb -0.3  1.2 2.1 0.8        1
 cc  0.5 -0.4 0.4 0.4        2
```

But I would like to mutate the quantile of all columns right after the corresponding column. 
Does anyone have any idea how can I do this in r with dplyr package with quantile and mutate functions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try using `dplyr::mutate_all` to apply `quantile` and then `cut` on all columns as:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% mutate_all(funs(quant = 
                       as.integer(cut(., quantile(.), include.lowest = TRUE))))

#     AA   BB  CC  DD AA_quant BB_quant CC_quant DD_quant
# 1  2.6 -0.3 2.5 2.3        4        2        4        4
# 2 -0.3  1.2 2.1 0.8        1        4        2        2
# 3  0.5 -0.4 0.4 0.4        2        1        1        1
```

**Data:**

```
df <- read.table(text="
AA   BB  CC   DD
aa  2.6 -0.3 2.5 2.3
bb -0.3  1.2 2.1 0.8
cc  0.5 -0.4 0.4 0.4",
header = TRUE)
```

Comment: Just in case one need to operate on a subset of columns, try `mutate_at`.